# Loading data from host to hdfs with python: no such file or directory error

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I want to load the file ad.py from my host (ubuntu 16.04 lts) into my input folder in hdfs with a python script. What I found so far is the following:

```
import subprocess


def run_cmd(args_list):
        """
        run linux commands
        """
        # import subprocess
        print('Running system command: {0}'.format(' '.join(args_list)))
        proc = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        s_output, s_err = proc.communicate()
        s_return =  proc.returncode
        return s_return, s_output, s_err 


run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-put', '/home/mernst/Desktop/ad.py', 'hdfs://localhost:55760/input'])
(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-ls', 'hdfs://localhost:55760/input'])

print(out)
```

If I save the above code in a file (e.g. called myfile.py) and run it with python myfile.py in the bash, the file ad.py is not loaded into the input folder, but at least the list command works and I can see what files are stored in hdfs:

```
python python-hadoop.py
Running system command: hdfs dfs -put /home/mernst/Desktop/ad.py
/usr/local/bin/hdfs/input
Running system command: hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:55760/input
Found 4 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2017-09-21 15:59
hdfs://localhost:55760/input/1st_test
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup        393 2017-09-20 10:28
hdfs://localhost:55760/input/PySpark.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup         14 2017-09-19 14:50   
hdfs://localhost:55760/input/file.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup         46 2017-09-28 09:57 
hdfs://localhost:55760/input/streaming_kmeans_data_test.txt
```

However, if I run the script with sudo myfile.py the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python-hadoop.py", line 18, in <module>
(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-ls', 'hdfs://localhost:55760/input'])
File "python-hadoop.py", line 11, in run_cmd
proc = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)#cwd = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I googled the error and it seems to occur, when the args_list argument in subprocess.Propen is a string and not a list, but in myfile.py this is not the case, so I really don't know what is wrong here and any help would be great.

p.s.: I also tried shell = True in subprocess.Popen but with no success.

Comment: Can you please provide complete console output of your python script?

Comment: Did you try with absolute path of hdfs executable(e.g. /usr/hdp/current/hdfs/bin/hdfs) instead of just hdfs?

Comment: @Shubhangi yes I did try but the same error occurs, I added the console output, when the script is run without sudo